# How do you cope with so many index.cshtml pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

My project is littered with Index.cshtml pages and it's annoyingly confusing. Not to mention multiple pages named Create, Edit, Delete, etc. which also exist. Everything is fine from the end user's perspective but as a developer I continually have to check which Index page I'm working with (based on the containing folder name). How do you deal with this scenario and simplify development?

[image]

Comment: Not have files called Index.cshtml? "Index" doesn't need to be the "default action" in a controller.

Comment: Name each page according to its action AND feature area and use an `IPageRouteModelConvention` to sort out the routing: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/327/customising-routing-conventions-in-razor-pages

Comment: You can rename you `.cshtml` file to whatever you want, then use the [`@page directive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes-1) to keep the same URL.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question, because it's not opinion based: you might want to change the project's file names while not changing the URLs of your website. It's obvious that you can rename the cshtml files, but doing so would also change the URLs. Doing so while retaining the old routes is not obvious, and depends on whether you're using controllers or razor pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL and filename are tightly coupled by default in Razor Pages. You can decouple them, however, by changing the route via the `@Page` directive (which appears at the beginning of the `.cshtml` file). This allows you to rename a `.cshtml` file in your project yet retain the existing URL.

For example, rename the default page `Pages/Index.cshtml` to `Pages/Home_Index.cshtml` then change the `@Page` directive to `@Page "/"`.

Similarly you could rename the page `Pages/PCL/Index.cshtml` to `Pages/PCL/PCL_Index.cshtml` then change it's `@Page` directive to `@Page "/PCL"` The URLs do not change (no bookmarks are broken for the user) yet within your project your code files are clearly named.

[image]

An excellent write-up on the subject [can be found here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/02/routing-razor-pages.aspx) where the author adds this caveat:

> "...the RedirectToPage method must continue to use the Page's file name"

I'll add that a similar caveat applies to `asp-page=` tag helpers so in this case you'll want to change them to something like: `asp-page="/Home_Index"`

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, as said by @gunr2171 in a comment, it is not required to use Index as default page.

[Watch here for change the default routes of application.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Also, personally I try use less pages possible, merge similar page in one and load specific part with the `@Html.Partial()` function.

Answer (score -2):

You need to refactor your code by creating action methods with meaningful names and rename your views accordingly. It's fine to first focus on completion of a task at first step but once you complete your functionality its always a good practice to go back and refactor your code to achieve maintainability in future.